# What is the best way to use Unicode in C++ on iPhone?

Tags: c++, iphone, unicode

I want to create my C++ libraries with Unicode support so they can be reused on other platforms.

I have found the ICU (International Components for Unicode) project but I also found a [discuss about Apple rejecting for using ICU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427838/iphone-app-rejection-for-using-icu-unicode-extensions).

So how do you guys use Unicode in C++ on iPhone? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to use, in Unicode?
If you want to manipulate Unicode strings and format or parse things according to a locale, the standard APIs should be enough: std::wstring, std::locale, iconv(), etc…

Comment: Also note the ObjectiveC String object can load from, and save to, UTF-8 buffers.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone uses ICU internally. Check About»Legal.