# Is ICU a private framework on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, rules, icu

Is ICU considered to be a *private* framework in Apple terms?  It's not very clear to me whether the header files in `$SDK/usr/include/` are private or not.  I'd like to use functions like `u_strcasecmp` from `<unicode/ustring.h>`.

The header files are present so I make an assumption that it's not really private.  On the other hand I cannot find Apple documenting any ICU functions in their API [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html).

Comment: doesn't xcode warn you when you are using private API's? and as you are already saying if you can just include the header file the API is usually public..

Comment: I find questions like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427838/iphone-app-rejection-for-using-icu-unicode-extensions
It's a little old though.  That's why I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All frameworks **not described** in Apple reference and invisible in header files can be considered as 'Private' (hence not usable in an AppStore application).

All framework/method references present in headers but not in Apple reference documentation are considered 'Undocumented', and should not be used in AppStore apps (but sometimes, it does the trick...)

Answer (score 2):

No. It should not be a private framework. Apples stand on this may have changed since the time this question was posted.

The [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH15-SW12) explicitly mentions the availability of a modified ICU 4.2.1 version and the contained `ustring.h` header.