# Xcode: best way to localize one of the "Other" languages?

Tags: localization, xcode5, nslocale

In `Xcode 5 > Project > Info > Localizations` one can pick a language/region from `Other` section. Can one localize an app for a region/language that is *not* among the 32 languages found under `Settings.app > General > International > Language` *without* any extra code? And what about `InfoPlist.strings` and its **`CFBundleDisplayName`** localized to a region?

[image]

Take `Belarusian (be)`, for example. Can Xcode use `be.lproj` at runtime *without* any additional code (on my part)? Or must one [manually pick the locale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002397-SW4), i.e. using `[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]`?

Apart from `Localizable.strings` (for which one can provide code, if need be), I'm mostly concerned about `CFBundleDisplayName`: **can `CFBundleDisplayName` be localized to one of the `Other` languages/regions?** As far as I can tell, `InfoPlist.strings` (and `CFBundleDisplayName` within it) can't be manipulated from code.

---

Related:

- [Multiple Localized .strings Files in iOS App Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785455/multiple-localized-strings-files-in-ios-app-bundle)
- [Localizing apps for non-standard locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082495/localizing-apps-for-non-standard-locales)

---

I *could* have a separate `Target` for each of those `Other` languages:

- That is, localize those 32 supported languages under **`Target 32`** (for which Xcode can automatically pick correct `.lproj` directory).
- And `Belarusian` goes under say **`Target Be`** (and has only one `Localizable.strings` and `InfoPlist.strings`)?

Obviously, this would mean *a lot* of targets (and tiresome submit procedure). **Is this multiple-targets approach the best possible?**

Comment: +1 for `Belarusian` =). Have found a solution? I'm trying to do target specific localization, which i think is a good approach if you have few languages, but not 32.

Comment: @user1244109 Sadly, I haven't found a better solution than having a separate target for each language categorised under 'Other' in above screenshot. Luckily I only had 1 such 'other' language, but even that almost doubles your workload in iTunesConnect.