# is there any interface in iOS dealing with icu of ibm like android ?

Tags: ios

is there any interface in iOS dealing with icu of IBM like android ? Android integrated icu4c of [ibm](http://(http://api.apkbus.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html)) ，and i don’t know if iOS is? is there any open api in iOS can deal with bidirectional word?

Comment: Take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126233/how-to-build-icu-so-i-can-use-it-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?